# sh script not count top command

Tags: bash

I have written a script to check process is running or not on Ubuntu server(14.04),it work fine but while testing it, I have found that it not include top command count running in other terminal

Content of `check-process.sh`

```
 #!/bin/sh 
 OK=1
 CRITICAL=0
 PROCESS_NUM=$( ps -ef | grep $1 | grep -v "grep "|grep -v "sh"|wc -l )
 #echo $PROCESS_NUM

 if [ $PROCESS_NUM = $OK ]
 then
  echo "OK"
 elif [ $PROCESS_NUM = $CRITICAL ]
 then
  echo "CRITICAL"
 elif [ $PROCESS_NUM > $OK ]
 then
  echo "MULTIPLE process are runing"
 else
  echo "error"
 fi
```

And I run `top` command in two terminals, and run this script as follow:

```
./check-process.sh top
```

The output is `0 CRITICAL`, but when I run normal command `ps -ef |grep -v "grep "| wc -l` it gives two counts.

Comment: are you sure `grep -v "grep "|grep "sh"` isn't filtering too much for what you want ?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're not using `pgrep` for this?

Comment: "but when i run normal command `ps -ef |grep -v "grep "| wc -l` it gives two counts." -- You're saying you've only got 1 process running on your system (one of those counts is going to be the `ps` headers)? are you using containers (docker) or anything?

Comment: Use two == for the comparison and not one.

Comment: i have changes in my question @terdon

Comment: i have changes in my question ,i forggot to write -v in second grep in my question @fellcien

Comment: In your test `[ ... ]` construct, the `=` and `>` won't do what you expect. For numeric comparisons you should use `-eq` and `-gt`. Consider `[ 10 > 400 ]` vs `[ 10 -gt 400]` and look at the difference in results.

Comment: @RamanSailopal A single `=` is correct in `[ ... ]`.  It does a string comparison for equality.

Comment: @RamanSailopal in fact, using `=` is more correct than `==` since `=` is the portable, [POSIX way](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html). Of course, the OP shouldn't be using `==` *or* `=`, since those do string comparisons, but that's another issue.

Answer (score 6):

As has been pointed out in comments to the question, testing with `>` does not do an arithmetic comparison but a lexicographic one (so that `2 > 100` is true, for example), but only within `[[ ... ]]`.  In `[ ... ]` it is an ordinary output redirection operator.

The `grep -v "grep "` and `grep -v "sh"` filtering may also filter out legitimate processes from the `ps` output (for example, if you'd like to use your script on `grep` processes).

---

The following script implements the same logic, but uses `pgrep`:

```
#!/bin/bash

cmd=$1

pids=( $( pgrep "$cmd" ) )

case "${#pids[@]}" in
    0) echo 'No such process'  ;;
    1) echo 'One such process' ;;
    *) echo 'Many such processes'
esac
```

If you're running one `top` command in another terminal, running this script with `top` as its argument will report `One such process`.  Running `top` in two terminals will make it report `Many such processes`.

With variables, like you use:

```
#!/bin/bash

cmd=$1

pids=( $( pgrep "$cmd" ) )

critical=0
ok=1

case "${#pids[@]}" in
    $critical) echo 'No such process'  ;;
    $ok)       echo 'One such process' ;;
    *)         echo 'Many such processes'
esac
```

The script saves the PIDs returned from `pgrep` into an array (which is why this is a `bash` script rather than a `sh` script) and then tests against the length of the array.

The following is an adaption to `sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

cmd=$1

set -- $( pgrep "$cmd" )

critical=0
ok=1

case "$#" in
    $critical) echo 'No such process'  ;;
    $ok)       echo 'One such process' ;;
    *)         echo 'Many such processes'
esac
```

This `sh` script uses the only array that we have access to which is the array of positional parameters.  These (the positional parameters) are set to the PIDs generated by `pgrep` with `set` and the number of these is had from `$#`.

Comment: you could also do `count=$(pgrep "$cmd" | wc -l)` if you only need the count and not an array full of PIDs.